# Windows Authentication using Apache CFX wsdl2java

Tags: java, apache, wsdl, windows-authentication, wsdl2java

I am trying to use Apache CFX wsdl2java command on Mac OSX.

I have run this command ./wsdl2java .

The error I get is the following:  WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsdl definition from : 
Caused by : WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing ''.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:

I believe the reason I get this error is because it requires Windows Authentication.  I have tried to search on how to do this, but I have had no luck so far.

I would be extremely thankful for any help or ideas on this topic.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

If Axis 1.3, you can try

`wsdl2java -uri http://user:pass@myapp.example.com/service/myService.wsdl`

If Axis 1.4+ you can try

```
wsdl2java -http-proxy-user user -http-proxy-password pass -uri http://myapp.example.com/service/myService.wsdl
```

Comment: I noticed you didn't say Axis2 so I downloaded Axis 1.4.  I ran the following command:   java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java <url>.  I then got the authorization problem again.  This version seems to have two flags (U/P) but not the ones you have listed.  I tried  java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -U user -P pass url, however it still fails due to authentication.  I am assume U/P is basic authentication (not windows) but the flags for windows don't seem to be available.  Any more ideas?

Comment: If the goal is to build the client, maybe you should download and save the WSDL manually using your browser, and build the client from the local WSDL file.

Answer (score 0):

Use **singleWsdl** rather than wsdl, save it and reference the local copy in command parameters.

use **abc/service/myService.singleWsdl** rather than **abc/service/myService.wsdl**